# Amount of force in Saitama's normal punch

Tags: one-punch-man

We've all seen Saitama destroy (almost all of) his opponents in literally a single punch.

I would like to know what is the force in newtons of that punch (not the serious one's that he used with Lord Boros).

I saw in a reddit page where they calculated the weight of Rock Lee's leg trainers (the weights he wore on his legs, don't know their exact name) by analyzing the amount of debris that flew into the air when he dropped them. I think we can use a similar technique here?

Comment: That kind of analysis could get into some seriously weird stuff, as he blows giant holes in the bodies of giant fleshy foes and non-flesh foes alike.  On the physics side you also have to make some assumptions about Saitama (modelling the impactor as a perfectly rigid object seems reasonable, but what about density?).

Comment: 'giant fleshy foes and non-flesh foes alike'

We can just consider the giant one's for modelling